# SWT MenuBar on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swt, menubar

I have a tool that has a simple menu bar. The way it is it work properly on Windows, but not on Mac. On Mac, when I open the "About" window, the menu disappears. On Windows it's normal, but on Mac the menu should always seen. How can I achieve this?

My code: (please note it's under construction)

```
        Menu menuBar = new Menu(newShell, SWT.BAR);
        MenuItem cascadeFileMenu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        cascadeFileMenu.setText("&File");

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu(newShell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        cascadeFileMenu.setMenu(fileMenu);

        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem(fileMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        exitItem.setText("&Exit");

        exitItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                getShell().getDisplay().dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        MenuItem cascadeManageMenu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        cascadeManageMenu.setText("&Manage");

        Menu manageMenu = new Menu(newShell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        cascadeManageMenu.setMenu(manageMenu);

        MenuItem branchItem = new MenuItem(manageMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        branchItem.setText("&Branch Priority");

        MenuItem libraryItem = new MenuItem(manageMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        libraryItem.setText("&Library Priority");

        MenuItem blankItem = new MenuItem(manageMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        blankItem.setText("");
        blankItem.setEnabled(false);

        MenuItem historyItem = new MenuItem(manageMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        historyItem.setText("&Test Run History");

        MenuItem cascadeAboutMenu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        cascadeAboutMenu.setText("&About");

        Menu aboutMenu = new Menu(newShell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        cascadeAboutMenu.setMenu(aboutMenu);

        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem(aboutMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        aboutItem.setText("&About Library Test Manager");
        aboutItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                AboutWindow aboutWindow = new AboutWindow();
                aboutWindow.open(); 
            }
        });

        newShell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```